# Android: Audio is Playing but I am unable to hear

Tags: android, listview, android-mediaplayer, custom-adapter

I am taking a course on Udacity and building an app.

Question - **Audio is Playing but I am unable to hear??**

I came to know the audio is playing when I log the information in the WordAdapter.java file

Files are mentioned below -

NumbersActivity.java

```
package com.example.miwok;

{VARIOUS IMPORT SATEMENTS}

public class NumbersActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 private MediaPlayer audio;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.list);

    ArrayList<Word> words = new ArrayList<Word>();

    words.add(new Word("One", "lutti", R.drawable.number_one, R.raw.number_one));
    words.add(new Word("Two", "ottiko", R.drawable.number_two, R.raw.number_two));
    words.add(new Word("Three", "tolookosu", R.drawable.number_three, R.raw.number_three));

    WordAdapter itemsAdapter = new WordAdapter(this, words, R.color.category_numbers);
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    listView.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);
}
}
```

Word.java (Class)

```
package com.example.miwok;
public class Word {

private String mEnglishWord;
private String mMiwokWord;
private int mImageResourceId = NO_IMAGE_PROVIDED;
private int mAudioResourceId;

private static final int NO_IMAGE_PROVIDED = -1;

public Word(String englishTranslation, String miwokTranslation, int imageResourceId, int audioResourceId) {
    mEnglishWord = englishTranslation;
    mMiwokWord = miwokTranslation;
    mImageResourceId = imageResourceId;
    mAudioResourceId = audioResourceId;
}

public Word(String englishTranslation, String miwokTranslation, int audioResourceId) {
    mEnglishWord = englishTranslation;
    mMiwokWord = miwokTranslation;
    mAudioResourceId = audioResourceId;
}

public String getEnglishWord() {
    return mEnglishWord;
}

public String getMiwokWord() {
    return mMiwokWord;
}

public int getImageResourceId() {
    return mImageResourceId;
}

public int getAudioResourceId(){ return  mAudioResourceId; }

public boolean hasImage(){
    return mImageResourceId != NO_IMAGE_PROVIDED;
}
}
```

WordAdapter.java (Class)

```
package com.example.miwok;
{VARIOUS IMPORT SATEMENTS}

public class WordAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

private int mBackgroundColour;
private MediaPlayer audio;
public WordAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<Word> words, int colour){
    super(context, 0, words);
    mBackgroundColour = colour;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View listItemView = convertView;
    if(listItemView == null) {
        listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
    }

    Word currentWord = (Word) getItem(position);

    LinearLayout word_item = (LinearLayout) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.word_item);
    TextView miwokTextView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.miwok_word);
    TextView englishTextView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.english_word);
    ImageView wordImageView = (ImageView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.word_image);

    if (currentWord.hasImage()){
        wordImageView.setImageResource(currentWord.getImageResourceId());
        wordImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }else{
        wordImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    miwokTextView.setText(currentWord.getMiwokWord());
    englishTextView.setText(currentWord.getEnglishWord());

    View text_container = listItemView.findViewById(R.id.word_container);
    int color = ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), mBackgroundColour);
    text_container.setBackgroundColor(color);

    word_item.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Hi", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            audio = MediaPlayer.create(getContext(),  currentWord.getAudioResourceId());
            audio.start();
            Log.i("isplaying", String.valueOf(audio.isPlaying()));
        }
    });


    return listItemView;
}
}
```

list_item.xml -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="88dp"
android:id="@+id/word_item">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/word_image"
    android:layout_width="88dp"
    android:layout_height="88dp"
    android:background="@color/tan_background"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/word_container"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/miwok_word"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        tools:text="miwok" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/english_word"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        tools:text="english"/>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Again - **Audio is Playing but I am unable to hear.**

Comment: In your next question you must  mention your problem just for one time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try change WordAdapter.java (Class) `audio = MediaPlayer.create(getContext(),  currentWord.getAudioResourceId());` to `audio = MediaPlayer.create(getContext().getApplicationContext(),  currentWord.getAudioResourceId());`